# GradientBoostingClassifier.fit accepts sparse X, but .predict does not

Tags: python

I am trying to use `GradientBoosting` Classifier.I changed my training `data(X_train)` into Sparse Matrix using `Tfidf`. Passed through `GradientBoostingClassifier.fit.` It works fine. When I try to apply the model on my Test data.

It gives an error saying

> "A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use
>   X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array."

I used `X_test.toarray()` as well but gives `memory error`. Is there any way around this?

I am using Pipeline as below

```
    text_clf_1 = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words=STOPWORDS, 
    ngram_range=(1,2))),('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()), 'clf', 
    GradientBoostingClassifier(verbose=100,n_estimators=100))])
```

Training model : Works fine

```
text_clf = text_clf_1.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

While testing gives the above mentioned error:

```
    text_clf_1predicted = text_clf.predict(X_test)

Error : "A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array."
```

I saw one question being raised for this but my when I tried "X_test.toarray()", it gives error

```
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toarray'
```

Comment: on memory error, can you try will few examples and see,   text_clf_1predicted = text_clf.predict(X_test[:10].toarray())

Comment: Adding .toarray() to my test dataset, gives the following error:                               
        AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toarray'

Comment: you should then do type(Xtrain) and type(X_test) and see if they are same type, as far as i remember, GBOOST doesn't use list as inputs, probably on y_train

Comment: I am converting both X_train  & X_test into sparse matrix through Tfidf mentioned in the pipeline, than it passes through Gradientboostingclassifier. Tye module's .fit takes sparse matrix , but the .predict function doesnot take sparse matrix.

Comment: i am not sure what is wrong, but testing sake,can you you use the last 10  records from Xtrain and see in predicting text_clf.predict(X_train[10,20]), if it works then you can be sure that the problem is with X_test tranformation

Comment: After giving that code: it runs error:                                                                                                   
        TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is 
        required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

Comment: there is an issue with .predict .How to convert sparse matrix into dense numpy array. Because .toarray() doesnot work on list & my data is in list format. I tried .todense() also, that gives memory error

Comment: i guess probably, it would X_test.data() , here is an inteeresting documentation about working with sparse_matrix http://mbatchkarov.github.io/2014/10/10/rate_of_vocab_growth/

Comment: X_test.data() doesnot work. There are two ways given yo convert sparse matrix to dense matrix by using .toarray() & .todense(). Both give memory error.